# How to run bibtex without latex?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I have bibtex file. I want to run only bibtex without pdflatex. I know that bibtex will use aux file which can be generated by pdflatex.But Is there any some other way to run bib file on .bst file. Because I want my bib file to be styled as .bst file template. So, how to run bib file to get reference with defined structure.(command something like: bibtex filename). I dont have tex file. Just I want to run only bibtex file. And I don't need citations,just the structured reference is more than enough. Pls help!

Comment: Hi and welcome, you will need a little bit of LaTeX-code to get a page to print on. `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\nocite{*}\bibliographystyle{<yourStyle>}\bibliography{<YourBibname>}\end{document}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us assume you have the following files/setup:

- `mybibstyle.bst`
- `mybibliography.bib`

Create a file `myfile.aux` containing the following:

```
\relax 
\citation{*}
\bibstyle{mybibstyle}
\bibdata{mybibliography}
```

This is literally the output from compiling the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{mybibstyle}
\bibliography{mybibliography}
\end{document}
```

Now run

```
bibtex myfile
```

which reads `mybibliography.bib`, `myfile.aux` and `mybibstyle.bst` and creates the file `myfile.bbl` containing the `thebibliography` environment based on `mybibstyle.bst`.

Comment: If I create only aux file and run bibtex no pdf is produced. But if create and run tex file as you mentioned above, only then pdf is generated. I just want to create only aux file and run bibtex without that tex file. How to do it. Because that tex file causing unwanted errors which I don't need.

Comment: @vidhya - The *inputs* of a bibtex run are an `aux` file (generally created by a LaTeX run), a `bst` file, and one or more `bib` files; the *outputs* of a bibtex run are a `bbl` file (containing the formatted and sorted references) and a `blg` file (a log file). *No pdf file is created by bibtex, ever.* It would be useful if you edited your posting to indicate more precisely what the "unwanted errors which I don't need" may be.